# how to enlist whatsapp images programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, whatsapp

In my application i need to have list of images that are downloaded from whatsapp.

I am a newbie in android programing world.

please give me some guide line for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you can follow some steps :

1. check that whether whatsapp installed or not
2. if installed then check in which directory it keeps its downloaded image.
3. if it is a separate folder & can be accessible from outside of that app then you can normally use that images.
4. if it downloaded its image in a common directory then then it's not possible to find out which images are downloaded by whatsapp.

Thank you.

Comment: Ty..i found the path for it..